# Automated unit testing with graphical coverage reports on Windows

Tags: windows, unit-testing, automation, build-automation, code-coverage

My previous team used a combination of googletest, buildbot, gcov and Google Chart tools to provide us with project insight.  We used the Google Chart tools to generate graphs of unit test coverage vs time to identify trends.  We used the gcov reports to identify areas with the largest coverage gaps.  The information was used internally to the team.

Now I'm going to be working with a team that develops for Windows and doesn't have any of this infrastructure in place.  We're starting from *zero* unit test coverage and I'd like to start moving in the right direction.  I'm looking for suggestions on tool suites that have worked for the Windows developers out there.